# JS output sum from HTML input

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, I'm trying to get the "impressions" element.value to update as the user types in the budget field, what is the best practise to get a result? the impressions should be the budget*350.

```
<div class="col">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <div class="input-group-text">£</div>
                </div>
                <input id="budget" type="text" class="form-control" name="campaign_budget" placeholder="100" value="<?php if(!empty($campaign_budget)) { echo $campaign_budget; } ?>">
              </div>
              <small class="form-text text-muted">You will recieve <span id="impressions">0</span> with this budget.</small>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way, I've used static budget value for the demo purpose, you can modify and add your PHP code here.

```js
const impression = document.getElementById('impressions');
document.getElementById("budget")
  .addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    impression.innerHTML = e.currentTarget.value * 350;
  });
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">£</div>
    </div>
    <input id="budget" type="text" class="form-control" name="campaign_budget" placeholder="100" value="50">
  </div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">You will recieve <span id="impressions">0</span> with this budget.</small>
</div>
```